# a conformal mapping from the unit disk onto an interior ellipse

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I would like to know what a conformal mapping from the unit disk onto an interior ellipse is. Thank you.

Comment: If the ellipse is axes-aligned, then $x \to \alpha x$ and $y \to \beta y$.

Comment: How can you write this in the conplex-valued function form?

Comment: $a + b i \to \alpha a + \beta b i$.